# Ruby Enumerator and Enumerable interaction: StopIterator dependency

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I have just come across some interesting Enumerator behaviour. There seems to be some dependency in Enumerator on position in an Enumerable - once you have peeked the end of the Enumerable and a StopIteration has been raised, no extension of the Enumerable is noted by the Enumerator.

Two examples demonstrate:

```
a=[1, 2, 3]
e=a.each
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 
2.4.0 :027 > e.next
 => 1 
2.4.0 :028 > a.insert(1, 4)
 => [1, 4, 2, 3] 
2.4.0 :029 > e.next
 => 4 
2.4.0 :031 > e.next
 => 2
```

OK, so far, so good. But what about this. Let's define a method to extend an array when we hit the end:

```
def a_ext(a,enum)
  enum.peek
rescue StopIteration
  a << a[-1] + 1
end
```

Now let's see what happens when we use it

```
2.4.0 :012 > a=[1, 2, 3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.4.0 :013 > e = a.each
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
2.4.0 :016 > 3.times{e.next} 
 => 3
```

We have reached the end of the array - so call `a_ext` to extend the array

```
2.4.0 :018 > a_ext(a,e)
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.4.0 :019 > e.peek
StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

????!!

It looks like once you have hit StopIteration, the Enumerator won't check again to see if the Array (I guess in general, an Enumerable) has been extended.

Is this expected behaviour? a bug? a feature?

Why might you want to do this. Well - with a Hash you can set a default value by passing `Hash::new` a block - and you can pass a block to `Array::new`. But the block that `Array::new` takes as an argument only has the index as a key, not the Array and the index (like Hash::new whose block yields the hash and the key). So this makes it extremely ugly and difficult to build an array that can be extended while enumerating through it.

For example, image an appointments diary where you want to enumerate through to find the first free day. This is naturally an Array rather than a Hash (as it is ordered), but it is very hard to extend while iterating through it.

Thoughts?

Comment: IMHO you should avoid updating an array while iterating over it to avoid inconsistency. In your example you could use `find` or `find_index` instead of using an enumerator.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason is that `StopIteration` has a `result` attribute, that basically is known if and only the iteration loop has ended. Consider following three examples:

```
[1,2,3].enum_for(:reduce, :*)          # #1, delegated to Array#reduce

[1,2,3].enum_for(:each, method(:puts)) # #2, delegated to Array#each

o = Object.new
def o.each { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; 100 } # #3
```

Once the exception is thrown (created,) the value should be known (it’s btw `6` in the first case, `[1,2,3]` in the second and `100` in the third one.) That basically means that allowing re-entering the loop would introduce inconsistency (the value exists, but is not correct anymore.)

Enumerator must distinguish “in-the-loop” and “finished” states and it can’t go back from the latter to the former due to reasons I described above. That’s probably why it is implemented that way.

Comment: Hmm - but if you are looking at the StopIterator#result - you know you have reached the end. I take your point though.

I think that part of the problem is that #peek raises a StopIteration if the next value is undefined. This strikes me as a bit weird, as the idea of #peek is that it looks ahead, without incrementing. There should be a way of checking whether you are at the end without blowing up the enumerator.

Looking at the source, maybe #peek should raise a different error if you are at the end of the Enumerator

Comment: @Steve, if `peek` didn't raise an exception (which one can catch), how could it's return value indicate that the end of the enumerator had already been reached? `nil` can't be used as it might be produced by the enumerator. I suppose one could have an `Enumerator` method `end_reached?`.

Comment: Hi Cary, I think that the subtlety is that StopIteration can be used to return a value - so you couldn't use a StopIteration exception - it would have to be a different exception. I completely agree about the `nil` issue.  `end_reached?` returning `nil` would be preferable, as it would not raise an exception (with all the stack unwinding overhead)

Answer (score -1):

Realistically, I think that the answer is a custom Enumerator, as described here: [StackOverflow: enumerator cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455529/clone-an-enumerator-in-ruby?rq=1)

This is the sort of thing I have ended up with. Initialize takes a block which can be used to construct new elements at the end as required.

```
   class ArrayEnumerator
     def initialize(array, &block)
       @ary = array
       @block = block
       @n = 0
     end

     def peek
       @block.call(@ary,@n) if @n == @ary.length
       @ary[@n]
     end

     def next
        v = peek
        @n += 1
        v
     end
   end
```