# Can I create a proc in the context of itself?

Tags: ruby, closures, proc

Since a proc is an object, can I create a proc in the scope of its own instance?

For example:

```
prc = Proc.new do
  foo
end

def prc.foo
  123
end

prc.call
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

Either by changing `self` or by having an explicit `receiver` referring to the proc.

That receiver has to be evaluated dynamically, e.g. the following should work:

```
other_prc = prc.clone

def other_prc.foo
  456
end

other_prc.call
#=> 456  <- not 123
```

Which means that I cannot just "hard-code" it via:

```
prc = Proc.new do
  prc.foo
end
```

In other words: is there any way to refer to the procs instance from within the proc?

---

Another example without `foo`: (what to put for `# ???`)

```
prc = Proc.new do
  # ???
end

prc == prc.call #=> true

other_prc = prc.clone
other_prc == other_prc.call #=> true
```

Replacing `# ???` with `prc` would only satisfy `prc == prc.call` but not `other_prc == other_prc.call`. (because `other_prc.call` would still return `prc`)

Comment: Though not an answer, note: `prc = Proc.new do; def self.foo; 123; end; foo; end; prc.call #=> 123`.

Comment: Also, `def foo; 123; end; prc = method(:foo).to_proc; prc.call => 123`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland but those `foo` aren’t methods of `prc`, are they?

Comment: Hmm. 1st: `prc.methods.include?(:foo) #=> false`. 2nd:  `prc.method(:foo).owner #=> Object`.

Comment: Another thought: `prc1 = proc { |l| @l = l; def self.foo; @l.call; end; foo }; prc1.call ->{ 456 }` works too, which might help if you're trying to preserve the deferred execution semantics, but I'm not sure why this level of indirection is beneficial. I get that you're trying to dynamically define how your Proc is getting its values at execution time, but it just seems like the long way around when injecting literals as arguments or referring to a data object in the binding would be so much easier.

Comment: A Proc's execution is deferred. Until called, self points to the current binding, rather than the current instance of Proc. If you don't want to do a Binding#eval or inject a block, proc, or lambda when calling a "master proc", I don't see how you can do what you want at declaration time rather than during deferred execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general approach that is typically used in DSLs is referred to as the Clean Room pattern - an object you build for the purpose of evaluating blocks of DSL code. It is used to restrict the DSL from accessing undesired methods, as well as to define the underlying data the DSL works on.

The approach looks something like this:

```rb
# Using struct for simplicity.
# The clean room can be a full-blown class. 
first_clean_room = Struct.new(:foo).new(123)
second_clean_room = Struct.new(:foo).new(321)

prc = Proc.new do
  foo
end

first_clean_room.instance_exec(&prc)
# => 123

second_clean_room.instance_exec(&prc)
# => 321
```

It appears that what you are looking for is to have the Proc object itself serve as both the block and the clean room. This is a bit unusual, since the block of code is what you typically want to have reused on different underlying data. I suggest you consider first whether the original pattern might be a better fit for your application.

Nevertheless, having the Proc object serve as the clean room can indeed be done, and the code looks very similar to the pattern above (the code also looks similar to the approach you posted in your answer):

```rb
prc = Proc.new do 
  foo
end

other = prc.clone

# Define the attributes in each clean room

def prc.foo
  123
end

def other.foo
  321
end

prc.instance_exec(&prc)
# => 123

other.instance_exec(&other)
# => 321
```

You could also consider making the approach more convenient to run by creating a new class that inherits from Proc instead of overriding the native `call` method. It's not wrong per-se to override it, but you might need the flexibility to attach it to a different receiver, so this approach lets you have both:

```rb
class CleanRoomProc < Proc
  def run(*args)
    instance_exec(*args, &self)
  end
end

code = CleanRoomProc.new do 
  foo
end

prc = code.clone
other = code.clone

def prc.foo
  123
end

def other.foo
  321
end

prc.run
# => 123

other.run
# => 321
```

And if you cannot use a new class for some reason, e.g. you are getting a Proc object from a gem, you could consider extending the Proc object using a module:

```rb
module SelfCleanRoom
  def run(*args)
    instance_exec(*args, &self)
  end
end

code = Proc.new do 
  foo
end

code.extend(SelfCleanRoom)

prc = code.clone
other = code.clone

# ...
```

Comment: Actually, I was trying to find a solution to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62637661/477037). A proc that can hold its own state in instance variables looked promising but I couldn't find a way to achieve it (hence this question). In the end, I [solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777445/477037) using a separate object that holds the state, quite similar to your "clean room" approach.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I'm answering my own question

---

The solution is surprisingly simple. Just override `call` to invoke the proc via [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/BasicObject.html#instance_exec-method):

> Executes the given block within the context of the receiver *(obj)*. In order to set the context, the variable `self` is set to *obj* while the code is executing, giving the code access to *obj*'s instance variables. Arguments are passed as block parameters.

```
prc = proc { |arg|
  @a ||= 0
  @a += 1
  p self: self, arg: arg, '@a': @a
}

def prc.call(*args)
  instance_exec(*args, &self)
end
```

Here, the receiver is the proc itself and the "given block" is also the proc itself. `instance_exec` will therefore invoke the proc in the context of its own instance. And it will even pass any additional arguments!

Using the above:

```
prc
#=> #<Proc:0x00007f84d29dcbb0>

prc.call(:foo)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x00007f84d29dcbb0>, :arg=>:foo, :@a=>1}
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^
#                  correct object          passes args

prc.call(:bar)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x00007f84d29dcbb0>, :arg=>:bar, :@a=>2}
#                                                   ^^^^^^
#                                               preserves ivars

prc.instance_variable_get(:@a)
#=> 2 <- actually stores ivars in the proc instance

other_prc = prc.clone
#=> #<Proc:0x00007f84d29dc598>
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           different object

other_prc.call(:baz)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x00007f84d29dc598>, :arg=>:baz, :@a=>3}
#                                                   ^^^^^^
#                                               ivars are cloned

other_prc.call(:qux)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x00007f84d29dc598>, :arg=>:qux, :@a=>4}

prc.call(:quux)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x00007f84d29dcbb0>, :arg=>:quux, :@a=>3}
#                                                    ^^^^^^
#                              both instances have separate ivars
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have to confess I'm missing the point. In this kind of `Proc`, `self` is missed forever and depend on what is the purpose of this code you may find a different solution that leaves `self` to point dynamically to the context.

Comment: @GiuseppeSchembri what do you mean by _"`self` is missed forever"_?

Comment: Sorry, I mean inside the block you use to create the `Proc`, [this article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/03/12/understanding-instance-exec-in-ruby.html) could be just an example on how we could miss `self`.

Comment: @GiuseppeSchembri of course, there can only be one `self`. If you need the outer `self` as well, you could assign it to a variable and refer to that variable from within the proc, e.g. `context = self ; prc = proc { p self: self, context: context }`

Comment: you're right `self` is not lost, you pointed another good workaround, but eventually, you may have some code (your code or other people code) that do not follow this convention and rely on `self`. That said a good question and an excellent solution. Thumb up for the question (not for the excellent answer just because of the disclaimer).

Comment: @GiuseppeSchembri that's correct, the proc doesn't work like a normal proc anymore. But in the question I explicitly asked for _"a proc in the scope of its own instance [...] either by changing `self` or by having an explicit receiver"_.

Comment: You can fetch the original (outer) `self` from within the proc by calling `binding.eval('self')`. The reason for this is that changing `self` does not affect `binding`. So you can always use `binding` as a gateway to the outer context.

Answer (score 4):

The second Attempt Edited after comment

```rb
# This solution has a limit you have to return the `Proc` itself
with_proc = proc do |aproc, others|
  aproc.instance_variable_set(:@a, aproc.instance_variable_get(:@a) || 0)
  aproc.instance_variable_set(:@a, aproc.instance_variable_get(:@a) + 1)
  p self: aproc, arg: others, '@a': aproc.instance_variable_get(:@a)
  aproc
end

prc = with_proc.(with_proc, :foo)
# => {:self=>#<Proc:0x000055864be1a740@pro_self.rb:1>, :arg=>:foo, :@a=>1}

puts "prc: #{prc}"
puts "prc.equal?(with_proc): #{prc.equal?(with_proc)}"
# => prc: #<Proc:0x000055864be1a740@pro_self.rb:1>
# => prc.equal?(with_proc): true

prc.call(prc, :bar)
puts "prc @a: #{prc.instance_variable_get(:@a)}"
# => {:self=>#<Proc:0x000055864be1a740@pro_self.rb:1>, :arg=>:bar, :@a=>2}
# => prc @a: 2

other_prc = prc.call(prc.clone, :baz)
puts "other_prc: #{other_prc}"
# => {:self=>#<Proc:0x000055864be1a0b0@pro_self.rb:1>, :arg=>:baz, :@a=>3}
# => other_prc: #<Proc:0x000055864be1a0b0@pro_self.rb:1>


other_prc.call(other_prc, :qux)
#=> {:self=>#<Proc:0x000055864be1a0b0@pro_self.rb:1>, :arg=>:qux, :@a=>4}

prc.call(prc, :quux)
# => {:self=>#<Proc:0x000055864be1a740@pro_self.rb:1>, :arg=>:quux, :@a=>3}
```

With this solution you can return whatever is necessary

```rb
prc = proc do |ref_to_self, others|
  self_reference = ref_to_self.instance_variable_get(:@ident)
  self_reference.instance_variable_set(:@a, self_reference.instance_variable_get(:@a) || 0)
  self_reference.instance_variable_set(:@a, self_reference.instance_variable_get(:@a) + 1)
  p ({self: self_reference.instance_variable_get(:@ident),
    arg: others,
    '@a': self_reference.instance_variable_get(:@a)})
end
prc.instance_variable_set(:@ident, prc)
prc.call(prc, :foo)

puts "prc: #{prc}"

prc.call(prc, :bar)
puts "prc @a: #{prc.instance_variable_get(:@a)}"

other_prc = prc.clone
other_prc.instance_variable_set(:@ident, other_prc)
other_prc.call(other_prc, :baz)
puts "other_prc: #{other_prc}"

other_prc.call(other_prc, :qux)

prc.call(prc, :quux)
# {:self=>#<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d808@pro_self.rb:71>, :arg=>:foo, :@a=>1}
# prc: #<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d808@pro_self.rb:71>
# {:self=>#<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d808@pro_self.rb:71>, :arg=>:bar, :@a=>2}
# prc @a: 2
# {:self=>#<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d1f0@pro_self.rb:71>, :arg=>:baz, :@a=>3}
# other_prc: #<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d1f0@pro_self.rb:71>
# {:self=>#<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d1f0@pro_self.rb:71>, :arg=>:qux, :@a=>4}
# {:self=>#<Proc:0x00005559f1f6d808@pro_self.rb:71>, :arg=>:quux, :@a=>3}
```

First Attempt

Edited after comment. That I know there is not a direct way to reference a `Proc` object inside the block you pass to `new` I tried to get closer to your code using tap.
I hope this can help

```rb
def proc_reference_to_self(a_proc)
  first = Proc.new do
    puts "Hello"

  end.tap(&a_proc)
end

second_prc = Proc.new do |first|
  p first
  first.call
  puts "second_prc"
  p second_prc
end

# This execute second_prc as a block
proc_reference_to_self(second_prc)

# first and second are different objects but you can still reference first
# inside second_proc

# <Proc:0x000055603a8c72e8@ruby_array_of_paths.rb:75>
# Hello
# second_prc
# <Proc:0x000055603a8c7338@ruby_array_of_paths.rb:81>
```

Comment: What I want to do is access the proc instance from within the proc's block. I've added the singleton method `foo` just as an example. I don't want to override `call` – doing so doesn't invoke the block anymore.

Comment: I've added another example, hope that clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: At the end of your 2nd attempt, `prc.call` and `other_prc.call` will both return `456`. That's because `ident = other_proc` also changes the `ident` object `prc` refers to.

Comment: @Stefan yes you're right, when I said that this solution is not able to save a state I meant this it's up to the caller to assign `ident` the current proc, definitely, your solution is more elegant but I like the simplicity of this and is a kind of a pattern that can turn useful (I used this rebunding trick in an implementation of a stream, not lazy Enumerator,  this is why it came up to my mind).

Answer (score 4):

### Leverage the Outer Scope of the Closures

If I understand your question correctly, leveraging the outer scope of the closure may do what you want. This is admittedly a very contrived example that registers your nested Proc objects in an Array. The second Proc isn't created until the first one is called, but they both retain their bindings to the outer scope.

```
@procs = []
@foo   = 1

@procs << proc do
  # Don't keep re-registering the nested Proc on
  # subsequent invocations.
  @procs << proc { @foo + 1 } unless @procs.count == 2
  @foo
end

@procs.map &:call
#=> [1, 2]

@foo = 3
@procs.map &:call
#=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: The nesting is superfluous. You could just as well have `@procs << proc { @foo }` followed by `@procs << proc { @foo + 1 }`. What I'm trying to do is to dynamically access the proc's very own instance from within the proc's block.

Comment: @Stefan You *might* be able to find it in ObjectSpace, or access the current binding, but #self doesn't return the Proc (just the receiver, e.g. `binding.receiver`) until Proc#new returns. With the object reference in hand, you could #send or use [Binding#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Binding.html#method-i-eval) with the Proc as a receiver, but I'm still not really clear on what that buys you since any closure within the namespace just contains a reference to variables in the binding, preventing you from assigning different values to the same variable within the binding.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, *now* I think I understand what you mean. As I mentioned in the comments, it can be done by nesting closures. Because Procs/lambdas are anonymous, the closure nesting provides a way for the lambda to receive a dynamic reference to itself, thereby allowing it to `instance_eval` code in the context of `self`.

```rb
wrapped_dispatch = ->(f) { f[f] }

proc_wrapped = lambda do |myself|
  lambda do |n|
    myself.instance_eval do
      # in context of self
      bar(n)
    end
  end
end

def proc_wrapped.bar(n)
  p "bar #{n}"
end

wrapped_dispatch[proc_wrapped].call(123)
# => "bar 123"

# can also save it "unwrapped"
prc = wrapped_dispatch[proc_wrapped]

prc.call(123)
# => "bar 123"

# Very late binding to dynamic receiver
def proc_wrapped.bar(n)
  p "BAR #{n}"
end
prc.call(123)
# => "BAR 123"

# and if the "wrapped-ness" bothers you, link them together and delegate
proc_wrapped.define_singleton_method(:call) do |n|
  prc.call(n)
end

def proc_wrapped.bar(n)
  p "BBBBAAAARRRRR"
end
proc_wrapped.call(123)
# => "BBBBAAAARRRRR"

other_proc_wrapped = proc_wrapped.clone
wrapped_dispatch[other_proc_wrapped].call(123)
# => "BBBBAAAARRRRR"

def other_proc_wrapped.bar(n)
  p "foo #{n}"
end

wrapped_dispatch[other_proc_wrapped].call(123)
# => "foo 123"
proc_wrapped.call(123)
# => "BBBBAAAARRRRR"
```

I'm noticing this behavior is very similar to a class's instances (`Foo.new`) vs a class's singleton class (`Foo.singleton_class`), which makes sense since [closures and objects are equivalent](https://wiki.c2.com/?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent). This means if you really want behavior like this, you ought to just use a class, its singleton class, and its instances, as is idiomatic in Ruby.

Comment: You're basically returning `prc` from `clone`, i.e. you don't actually clone anymore. In your example, `prc` and `other_prc` are the same object: `prc.equal?(other_prc) #=> true`

Comment: Ok, fixed it. I'm not _just_ returning `prc` from `clone`, I'm implementing `clone` with a recursive "build the same thing again". "cloning a Proc" doesn't normally make sense -- its normal use is to copy values or an object (encapsulating values).

Comment: `instance_eval` isn't needed, you can just write `ret = Proc.new { ret.foo }`. In Ruby, a proc is both, a closure and an actual object (an instance of `Proc`). Or maybe the closure is wrapped in an instance of `Proc`. What I want to do is to dynamically access the instance that holds this closure from within the closure. Overriding `clone` to create a new proc that "statically" resolves to itself (or its `foo`) makes my example pass, but it's not what I really want. It's more or less `prc = Proc.new { prc.foo }` followed by `other_prc = Proc.new { other_prc.foo }` just hidden behind `clone`.

Comment: Hm, I see. I think that should be possible with a nested Proc to provide that dynamicism -- I'll give it a try later. You definitely can't do it otherwise, as the scope of a Proc should be set when defined, otherwise it wouldn't be a closure. Btw this is a rather academic exercise, as I'm sure there're better ways to implement whatever ultimate external behavior you want the code to have (what is it, anyway?)

Comment: @Stefan just updated, that's what you were looking for, right?

Comment: Nice! One more level of indirection and we have the Y combinator ;-)